# Does $dx$ have a particular "direction"?

Tags: calculus

While solving some questions on definite integration, I faced some problems regarding setting the lower and upper limit. Consider this very famous rocket propulsion problem:

> A rocket together with its fuel has a mass $m_0$ at $t=0$. Gas is ejected at a constant rate $r = -\frac{dm}{dt}$ and at a constant velocity $u$ relative to the rocket. Express the velocity of rocket as a function of time(ignore gravity).

**My Approach**

Let the mass of the rocket at time $t$ be $m$. [image: rocket momentum diagram] Applying conservation of linear momentum we get $mv = (m-dm)(v+dv)+dm (v-u) \implies mdv = udm$ or $$\frac{1}{u} dv = \frac{dm}{m}$$. Now this is where the main problem arises. When I integrate the left hand side and right hand side from initial to final conditions( i.e., velocity from $0$ to $v$ and mass from $m_0$ to $m(= m_0 -rt)$ I get wrong answer. In the solution, they put the limit in mass from $m$ to $m_0$. I guessed that I might be because I have $m - dm$ instead of $m+dm$. But, I am searching for some more clear and rigorous argument. Also, I want to know the proper method to set lower and upper limits so that there are no chances of error.

Note:

Please don't close my question seeing some Physics involved in it. My main doubt is related to Calculus so I posted it here.

Comment: In general as long as you integrate between two points that correspond to the same time, the order of the limits of integration doesn't actually matter. It changes the sign on one side and on the other side so it washes out. So something else must be going wrong. That said in general you should just integrate in time and then change variables rather than immediately integrating on both sides in different variables.

Comment: The limits should correspond (mass at corresponding velocity). However, you have chosen the sign on $dm$ to be positive, whereas mass is decreasing. It’s better to write $+dm$ at the outset.

Answer (score 3):

Ted Shifrin has already pointed out where you made your mistake, and how to fix it, [in the comments above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590296/does-dx-have-a-particular-direction/4590417#comment9665669_4590296). Since you wanted a more rigorous approach, though, I will go ahead and do my best to answer the question you asked.

On its own, $dx$ doesn't really have a value. It is a piece of notation that is easily (and often) abused by treating it as though it *does* have a value, though.

Here's how I would proceed, being a little more rigorous (and less abusive of the notation).

The rocket's mass is a scalar function $m(t)$ with respect to time, $m(0)=m_0,$ and it has been given that $r=-\frac{dm}{dt},$ where $r$ is a positive constant in unit mass per unit time. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus shows that $$m(t)-m_0=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dm}{ds}\,ds=-r\int_{0}^{t}\,ds=\bigl[-rs\bigr]_{s=0}^{t}=-rt,$$ and so $m(t)=m_0-rt,$ as you calculated.

Observe that the mass of the rocket will not reach $0,$ but will remain positive. In particular, this means that $m_0>rt,$ and so the model is only valid for $0\leq t\leq T,$ for some $T<\frac{m_0}{r}.$ **This will be important at the end.**

Now, our reference frame has been chosen such that the initial velocity of the rocket is $\vec 0$ and the total momentum of the system is $\vec 0.$ We'll specify the "negative" direction to be the direction that the gas is being ejected.

Letting $\vec p_1(t)$ signify the momentum of the rocket at time $t$ and $\vec p_2(t)$ the combined momentum of all the ejected gas at time $t$, we have that both $\vec p_1(0)$ and $\vec p_2(0)$ are zero vectors. The reason $\vec p_1(0)$ is a zero vector is because if $\vec v(t)$ represents the rocket's velocity vector at time $t,$ then $\vec v(0)$ is a zero vector. The reason $\vec p_2(0)$ is a zero vector is that, at time $0,$ no gas has yet been ejected from the rocket--or more accurately, if any *has* been, it is safe to ignore it as far as our system is concerned--which means the ejected gas's total mass is the $0$ mass scalar. For $t>0,$ we will have that $\vec p_1(t)$ and $\vec p_2(t)$ will be nonzero vectors, respectively in the positive and negative directions, but regardless, conservation of momentum tells us that $\vec p_1(t)+\vec p_2(t)$ is a zero vector for all $t.$

We already have an explicit formula for $\vec p_1(t)$ in terms of $m(t)$ and $\vec v(t).$ Namely, we have $\vec p_1(t)=m(t)\vec v(t).$ Since we know that $\vec p_1(0)$ and $\vec p_2(0)$ are both zero vectors and that $\vec p_1(t)+\vec p_2(t)$ is a zero vector for all $t,$ we also know that know that $$\frac{d\vec p_1}{dt}=-\frac{d\vec p_2}{dt}\\\frac{d}{dt}\left[m(t)\vec v(t)\right]=-\frac{d\vec p_2}{dt}\\m(t)\frac{d\vec v}{dt}+\frac{dm}{dt}\vec v(t)-\frac{d\vec p_2}{dt}.$$

The velocity of the gas as it emerges will always be $\vec v(t)+\vec u$ (right up until the point that the rocket is completely *out* of gas, which will occur before the mass of the rocket reaches $0$), where $\vec u$ represents the (negative) velocity of the emerging gas relative to the rocket's frame of reference. The mass emerges at a rate of $r,$ and the product of $r$ and $\vec v+\vec u$ gives us the rate of change of the (total) ejected gas's momentum with respect to time. That is, $$\frac{d\vec p_2}{dt}=r\bigl[\vec v(t)+\vec u\bigr],$$ and so $$m(t)\frac{d\vec v}{dt}-r\vec v(t)=-r\bigl[\vec v(t)+\vec u\bigr]\\m(t)\frac{d\vec v}{dt}-r\vec v(t)=-r\vec v(t)+-r\vec u\\m(t)\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=-r\vec u,$$ and since $m(t)$ never actually reaches $0,$ then $$\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=-\frac{r}{m(t)}\vec u,$$ or equivalently, $$\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=-\frac{r}{m_0-rt}\vec u.$$

Since $\vec v(t)=\vec v(t)-\vec v(0)=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{d\vec v}{ds}\,ds,$ then $$\vec v(t)=-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{r}{m_0-rs}\vec u\,ds\\\vec v(t)=-\vec u\int_{0}^{t}\frac{r}{m_0-rs}\,ds\\\vec v(t)=-\vec u\bigl[-\ln(m_0-rs)\bigr]_{s=0}^{t}\\\vec v(t)=\vec u\bigl[\ln(m_0-rs)\bigr]_{s=0}^{t}\\\vec v(t)=\vec u\bigl[\ln(m_0-rt)-\ln(m_0)\bigr],$$ and so by rules of logarithms, $$\vec v(t)=\ln\left(1-\frac{r}{m_0}t\right)\vec u.$$ This is, in fact, a nonzero vector in the positive direction for all valid* nonzero $t,$ since $\vec u$ is in the negative direction, and $m_0,r$ are positive!

*This is why it ***really matters*** that our model is only valid where $0\leq t\leq T$ for some $T<\frac{m_0}{r}.$

---

As a slight caveat, it turns out not to be as important that $t\geq 0,$ as long as the rocket was, in fact, ejecting gas at the same rate prior to time $0.$ The formula above for  gives us a nonzero velocity vector for the rocket in the *negative* direction, but all that really means is that the rocket wasn't moving as quickly, yet, as it would be at time $0,$ so our frame of reference was actually catching up to the rocket! This is why I said it was safe to ignore any previously-expelled gas, as far as our system is concerned.

Comment: You also could cut off the ejection process at a $T<m_0/r$, representing not all the mass being gas, and then continue a ballistic trajectory from there.

Comment: Exactly. We need to adjust the model piecewise, thereafter. And for that matter, prior to the beginning of the gas ejection.